# File store in mixed network

Tags: windows, mac, file-sharing

Technically what is the best option for a central file store in a Windows/MAC/Linux network?
Experiences and views welcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to invest in some hardware; QNAP or Synology NAS devices would work. These have worked for me fine.
If you have old machine and some hard drives laying around, you could install [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org/).
Both options support user accounts, protocols for all platforms that you have (Windows, Mac, Linux); web based management (if needed) etc.

Comment: I like the look of the Synology device.  Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Dropbox, it supports LAN Syncing too.
It will be good, if you ever need access to the files outside your network.

Or this is what you may be looking for:
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/set-ftp-server-core-ftp/